# Speed up NFS Home Folder mount

Tags: mount, nfs, ubuntu-server

I have a (virtual) cluster of Ubuntu servers where one master node offers an NFS folder that the slaved nodes mount. It serves as the home folder for an MPI user account.

The nodes all manage to connect to it just fine but I have one problem. Whenever a machine starts up or reboots it takes upwards of a minute for the nodes to reconnect to the NFS directory. This wreaks havoc with my automation as I'm forced to make the machine sleep for 2 minutes during the boot sequence just so my startup scripts are able to access files on the NFS.

Is there any way of speeding the mounting process up?

**EDIT**

Interestingly enough, while mucking about with my startup scripts and their sleep timer, I've discovered that one of my nodes is able to reconnect to the NFS directory without any delay. Unfortunately all the other still have to deal with delays. Given that they're all supposed to be clones of one another I'm not really sure what caused this discrepancy.